# Deleting empty records from a file starting with specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a file containing DBLP dataset which consists of bibliographic data in computer science. I want to delete some of the records with missing information.  For example, I want to delete records with the missing venue. In this dataset, the venue is followed by '#c'.

In this code, I am splitting documents by the title of manuscripts ("#*"). Now, I am trying to delete records without venue name.

Input Data:

```
#*Toward Connectionist Parsing.

#@Steven L. Small,Garrison W. Cottrell,Lokendra Shastri

#t1982

#c

#index14997


#*A Framework for Reinforcement Learning on Real Robots.

#@William D. Smart,Leslie Pack Kaelbling

#t1998

#cAAAI/IAAI

#index14998

#*Efficient Goal-Directed Exploration.

#@Yury V. Smirnov,Sven Koenig,Manuela M. Veloso,Reid G. Simmons

#t1996

#cAAAI/IAAI, Vol. 1

#index14999
```

My code:

```
inFile = open('lorem.txt','r')
Data = inFile.read()
data = Data.split("#*")
ouFile = open('testdata.txt','w')
for idx, word in enumerate(data):
    print("i = ", idx)
    if not('#!' in data[idx]):
        del data[idx]
        idx = idx - 1
    else:
        ouFile.write("#*" + data[idx])
ouFile.close()
inFile.close()
```

Expected Output:

```
#*A Framework for Reinforcement Learning on Real Robots.

#@William D. Smart,Leslie Pack Kaelbling

#t1998

#cAAAI/IAAI

#index14998

#*Efficient Goal-Directed Exploration.

#@Yury V. Smirnov,Sven Koenig,Manuela M. Veloso,Reid G. Simmons

#t1996

#cAAAI/IAAI, Vol. 1

#index14999
```

Actual Output:
An empty output file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) will give you an index of sub-string, or -1 if the sub-string does not exist.

```py
DOCUMENT_SEP = '#*'

with open('lorem.txt') as in_file:
    documents = in_file.read().split(DOCUMENT_SEP)

with open('testdata.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for document in documents:
        i = document.find('#c')
        if i < 0:  # no "#c"
            continue
        # "#c" exists, but no trailing venue information
        if not document[i+2:i+3].strip():
            continue
        out_file.write(DOCUMENT_SEP)
        out_file.write(document)
```

- Instead of closing manually, I used a `with` statement.
- No need to use index; deleting an item in the middle of loop will make index calculation complex.
- Using regular expressions like `#c[A-Z]..` will make the code simpler.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code wasn't working is because there's no `#!` in any of your entries.
If you want to exclude entries with empty `#c` fields, you can try this:

```
inFile = open('lorem.txt','r')
Data = inFile.read()
data = Data.split("#*")
ouFile = open('testdata.txt','w')
for idx, word in enumerate(data):
    print("i = ", idx)
    if not '#c\n' in data[idx] and len(word) > 0:
        ouFile.write("#*" + data[idx])
ouFile.close()
inFile.close()
```

In general, try not to delete elements of a list you're looping through. It can cause a lot of unexpected drama.